# The use of Schauder fixed point in ladyzehskaya

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, regularity-theory-of-pdes

The book Linear and Quasilinear equations of parabolic type gives the uniform parabolic pde theory in the literature.
Ladyzhenskaya use Leray-Schauder rather than Schauder fixed point theorem. why?
When would one use Leray-Schauder over Schauder fixed point?
I don't understand why ladyzenskaya chosen to use Leray-Schauder over Schauder fixed-point theorem.

Appreciate any comments.

Comment: Can you prove existence with both methods?

Comment: I think the reason Leray-Schauder is used over Schauder method is because she want to connect the problem with a 1-parameter family of problem of the same type, see p.370 and p.371 p.291 of her book on quasilinear elliptic pde

Answer (score 0):

In applications one of the drawbacks of Schauder's fixed point theorem is the 
invariance condition $T (D) \subset D$ which has to be guaranteed for a bounded 
closed convex subset $D$ of a Banach space. The Leray-Schauder principle makes it possible to avoid such a condition and requires instead that a 
'boundary condition' is satisfied.